# Mysql insert inside a for loop in node js

Tags: node.js

I am very new in Node js and I am trying to understand one thing here:

as you can see there is a for loop iterating trough a row from a database selection.

```
connection.query(/*select data*/)
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var fulladdress = rows[i]['agency_full_address'];
    var agency = rows[i]['agency_id'];
    console.log('before:' + agency)
        geocoder.geocode(fulladdress)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log('after:' + agency)
                /*populate table with agency and coordenates*/
            })

            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            });
}
```

The first thing I do after the loop is to take the full address and the agency id and log that result like this:

```
before: 1
before: 2
before: 3
```

Then I run a function to convert the full address of an agency into lat and long coordenates and it works fine. After that I print again the agency id but then I have the next result

```
after: 3
after: 3
after: 3
```

It's only printing the last id. I guess it is because nodejs is asynchronous. but how can I solve this problem in this case. I need the agency id be the same before and after so I can use these values to populate a table in a database but in this moment is being populated like this

```
agency_id |  latitude  |  longitude  |
    3     | 63.254587  |  -39.221144 |
    3     | 58.256254  |  -48.656989 |
    3     | 48.256254  |  -58.356979 |
```

and should be like this

```
agency_id |  latitude  |  longitude  |
    1     | 63.254587  |  -39.221144 |
    2     | 58.256254  |  -48.656989 |
    3     | 48.256254  |  -58.356979 |
```

Comment: I suspect this strangeness is due to the `closure` function you got in the `then` clause of `geocoder.geocode(fulladdress)`. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Nodejs is asynchronous and event driven. What you should do is implementing a callback after each loop. You may like to use "async"

[Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Isn't the function in the `.then(...)` clause the callback for his promise?

Comment: @SamuelToh I agree, I have been using .then() or .all() as callback for this kind of sql query for a couple months now, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

So following the advice of BK Hien and most of the answers about busy loops in node js I gave a try to async module and it works synchronously now (the problem with my inicial code was the for loop never waited for the function inside of it to be executed )

first you gonna need to install the async module:

```
npm install async --save
```

and require the module:

```
var async =require('async');
```

and this is the final code working:

```
connection.query(/*select data*/)

async.forEachOf(rows, function(value, key, callback) {

            geocoder.geocode(value['agency_full_address'], function(err, res){
                if(err) return callback(err);
                try{
                connection.query('INSERT INTO coordenates SET coordenate_agency_id = ?, coordenate_latitude = ?, coordenate_longitude = ?', [value['agency_id'], res[0].latitude, res[0].longitude], function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                });}catch (e){
                    return callback(err);
                } callback();
            })
        })
```

you can check the documentation in http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html